# Rendered não Funciona em dataTable

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Boa tarde.

Tenho um problema simples. Entretanto, estou com dificuldades para resolver.
Tenho esses 2 métodos para controlar meu Rendered do `dataTable`:

```java
// Filtra o simulado..
    @Transactional
    public void gerarSimulado() {
        this.questoes = simuladoFiltroDAO.geraSimuladoPorFiltro(
                cursoSelecionado.getCodigo(), this.complexidadeSelecionada,
                this.numeroDeQuestoesSimulado);
        isMostraQuestoesGeradasSimulado();
        this.simulado.setNumeroQuestoesSimulado(numeroDeQuestoesSimulado);
        this.simulado.setCurso(cursoSelecionado);
        this.simulado.setQuestoes(questoes);

    }
```

Em especial esse método `boolean`, que controla o rendered:

```java
public boolean isMostraQuestoesGeradasSimulado() {
            return this.questoes != null;
        }
```

Na minha página em xhtml, eu tenho:

```xml
    <p:dataTable id="exibePerguntas" rendered="#{gerarSimuladoBean.mostraQuestoesGeradasSimulado}" var="questao" paginator="true"
                            rowsPerPageTemplate="2,3,5,10,12" paginatorPosition="bottom" value="#{gerarSimuladoBean.questoes}">
            <p:column headerText="Perguntas">
                        <br></br>
                        <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{questao.pergunta}"  />
            </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Código do botão gerar simulado:

```
 <p:commandButton id="geraSimulado" value="Gerar Simulado" action="#{gerarSimuladoBean.gerarSimulado}" 
                    icon="ui-icon-search" update="@this exibePerguntas">
                </p:commandButton>
```

Pela lógica, ao clicar no botão "gerar simulado", já é para aparecer as perguntas né? Já que o questões vão ser populadas e o resultado vai dar `true`. Só que não é isso que tá acontecendo. Alguém sabe o porque?

Comment: coloca o código do botão aí. por favor.

Comment: @RafaelTSCS o código do botão Gerar simulado é o método  public void gerarSimulado(). O método tá la em cima!

Comment: falo do codigo JSF (HTML)

Comment: Beleza, vou colocar.

Comment: @RafaelTSCS ta aí mano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está mandando o botão atualizar o dataTable "exibePerguntas", só que esse datatable tem um rendered. Assim, se não houver nada pra mostrar, esse datatable não existe e o botão não tem oq atualziar.

Mude o update="" do botão para algum outro containter que não tenha rendered. Ou para o próprio @form se ele e a tabela estiverem no mesmo formulário.

verifique também se as questões foram realmente geradas.

Comment: pode crer RafaelTSCS funcionou direitinho. Alterei o update para @form e foi.